# How to prevent Cloud Run nginx alpine container logging at Notice level

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-run

Google Cloud Run seems to alter / ignore the normal behaviour of nginx alpine logging.

Container is configured as per here: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/deploy-react-nginx-cloud-run, which uses the standard nginx alpine image. This image has the following set in the base nginx.conf:

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
```

The expected behaviour is that warn level logs and higher only would be logged. What is actually happening is notice level logging. This means my Google cloud logging is full of unnecessary lines like this:

```
[notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
[notice] 1#1: nginx/1.21.3
[notice] 1#1: built by gcc 10.3.1 20210424 (Alpine 10.3.1_git20210424)
[notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 4.4.0
[notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 25000:25000
[notice] 1#1: start worker processes
```

These logs do not occur when running the container locally.

I have tried to force the error log setting manually on the Dockerfile CMD e.g.:

```
nginx -g 'daemon off; error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;'"
```

As well as various different error log configs in the conf files. No change I make appears able to influence the generation of these logs on Cloud Run.

Comment: Ok - so the default error log level was changed in nginx between version 1.19 and 1.21.

Comment: So to explain the problem: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf now has notice set as the default error log level.
Turns out my local machine had 1.19. Updating, I now get the same behaviour. So this isn't a cloud run issue - it's nginx alpine changing behaviours.